# How to save serial input to one textfile with automatic timestamp?

Tags: qt

I want to save a lot of serial data to one text file in Qt with automatic timestamp.

Here is what I have tried:

```
void Measure::saveFile(QString buffer)
{
    QString  log_file = SAVE_DATA_LOG+QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy_hh:mm:ss")+".txt";
    QFile file(log_file);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
    stream << buffer;
    file.flush();
    file.close();
}
```

The problem is, that a new file is created every second. How can I save the data in one text file with a timestamp?

Comment: where does `stream` come from?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `QIODevice::Truncate` flag, this will empty the file

On top of that you should not make the filename with the current timestamp. You can write the timestamp to the file with the following code:

```
QString log_file = SAVE_DATA_LOG + ".txt";
QFile file(log_file);
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
QTextStream out(&file);
out << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy_hh:mm:ss") << data;
```

---

**Edit:**

I think I start to understand what you mean: you want to create one text file which is named after the datetime when you started the program and then append to that file. So here is my second go:

```
class Measure {

  public:
    Measure():
        log_file(SAVE_DATA_LOG+QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy_hh:mm:ss")+".txt"),
    {
    }

    ~Measure()
    {
    }

    void saveFile(QString buffer)
    {
        QFile file(log_file);
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << buffer;
        file.flush(); //optional
        file.close();
    }

  private:
    QString log_file;
    QTextStream stream;
};
```

This uses the constructor to make the filename, you could also make a function to reset the filename etc.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

If I change to:
void Measure::saveFile(QString buffer)
{
    

    QString  log_file = SAVE_DATA_LOG"1.txt";
    QFile file(log_file);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);

    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy_hh:mm:ss") << buffer;
    stream << buffer;
    file.flush();
    file.close();

Program saves a time stamp into a file, but i want save a filename, like "11.09.2018_08:27:04.txt"

Comment: For better understanding - I get some data from UART every second and want save it to ONE text file. And I need save a start timestamp into a name of text file.
The code: 
 void Measure::saveFile(QString buffer)
{
    QString  log_file = SAVE_DATA_LOG+QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy_hh:mm:ss")+".txt";
    QFile file(log_file);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);

    QTextStream stream(&file);

    stream << buffer;
    file.flush();
    file.close();
} makes every second a new textfile with new timestamp,but I want write in just one text file!

Comment: @Fracture I edited the post to be more complete, if this is not what you want, then please elaborate (and try to use backtick (the one left of the `1` on an american keyboard) in your comment for code-blocks)

Comment: No, sorry, it don't works! I just scribe a time stamp into a file and not in filename! I will insert my code again in the top!

Comment: Oh, Thank you! I will try it now!

Comment: Hmm, 2 error warning: "QFile::QFile(const QFile&) is private" -> "Q_DISABLE_COPY(QFile)" and "within this context: QFile file(log_file);" -> "use of deleted function QFile::QFile(const QFile&)"   Do you know what is maybe wrong?

Comment: Oh sorry, the log_file should be QString. I will edit the answer

Comment: QIODevice::write (QFile, ""): device not open
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified